# How to implement Drag and Drop in FileExplorer - VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, drag-and-drop, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to implement TreeDragAndDropController in FileSystemProvider and FileExplorer classes (fileExplorer.ts) using the TestViewDragAndDrop class (testViewDragAndDrop.ts), both examples created by VSCode MS Team, but without success. I can't handle data in handleDrop function and I don't know if I'm setting the dropMimeTypes and dragMimeTypes correctly, even setuping it based in the documentation.

Here's part of my code

```
export class FileSystemProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<Entry>, vscode.FileSystemProvider, vscode.TreeDragAndDropController<Entry> {
    private _onDidChangeFile: vscode.EventEmitter<vscode.FileChangeEvent[]>;
    private _elementEntry: Entry;

    constructor(elementEntry: Entry) {
        this._onDidChangeFile = new vscode.EventEmitter<vscode.FileChangeEvent[]>();
        this._elementEntry = elementEntry;
    }

    dropMimeTypes = ['application/vnd.code.tree.fileExplorer'];
    dragMimeTypes = ['text/uri-list'];

    public async handleDrag(source: Entry[], dataTransfer: vscode.DataTransfer, token: vscode.CancellationToken) {
        dataTransfer.set('application/vnd.code.tree.fileExplorer', new vscode.DataTransferItem(source));
    }
    public async handleDrop(target: Entry | undefined, source: vscode.DataTransfer, token: vscode.CancellationToken) {
        const transferItem = source.get('application/vnd.code.tree.fileExplorer');

        console.log("handleDrop", { transferItem });
```

Here's the projetct based on Tree-View-Sample repository, that I'm trying to emulate VSCode Explorer and use the drag and drop in fileExplorer.ts.